# How can I get previous fragment index after swipe in android?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I know that using ViewPager I can get current fragment index but how can I get previous fragment index?

Its not a problem when I go forward (i-1) but how about going backward? Maybe their is a way to detect which direction I swipe? or something else

Answer (score 0):

I just answered a similar question --> [Holding references to the fragments returned by PagerAdapter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23903456/2017375). In that question the user wants to connect the current fragment to a Server and disconnect the previous one, so only one connection is active at any given time.